# Разность значений из словаря python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сопоставить и найти разность значений?

```
а={'a3':3,'a1':1,'a2':2} 
d={'b1':2,'b3':3,'b2':1}
```

Надо получить:

```
{'a1': 1, 'a2': -1, 'a3': 0}
```

Comment: Вы бы добавили свои наработки хотя бы, вопросы с таким содержанием здесь не очень приветствуются.

Comment: На английском SO есть подробный разбор вопроса: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632244/difference-in-a-dict

Answer (score 3):

Добавлю решение с помощью генератора:

```
a={'a3':3,'a1':1,'a2':2} 
d={'b1':2,'b3':3,'b2':1}

A = {key: d[key.replace('a','b')] - val for key, val in a.items()}
```

Получаем:

```
{'a1': 1, 'a2': -1, 'a3': 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь модулем Pandas:

```
In [16]: import pandas as pd

In [17]: s1 = pd.Series(a)

In [18]: s2 = pd.Series(d)

In [19]: s1
Out[19]:
a1    1
a2    2
a3    3
dtype: int64

In [20]: s2
Out[20]:
b1    2
b2    1
b3    3
dtype: int64

In [21]: s2.index = s2.index.str.replace('b','a')

In [22]: s2
Out[22]:
a1    2
a2    1
a3    3
dtype: int64

In [23]: s2 - s1
Out[23]:
a1    1
a2   -1
a3    0
dtype: int64
```

результат:

```
In [24]: (s2 - s1).to_dict()
Out[24]: {'a1': 1, 'a2': -1, 'a3': 0}
```

Comment: + Пандас на все случаи жизни )

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч, согласен! :-D

Comment: @andreymal, можно конечно попробовать решить эту задачу при помощи Tensorflow, но мне лень ;-)

Comment: @MaxU https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736401/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-matplotlib-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80 посмотри )

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч, посмотрел... ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
{ak: d[bk]-a[ak] for ak, bk in zip(*map(sorted, (a, d)))}
```

для произвольного числа словарей

```
from functools import reduce
ds = {'a3':3,'a1':1,'a2':2}, {'b1':2,'b3':3,'b2':1}, {'v1':2,'v3':3,'v2':1}, {'s1':2,'s3':3,'s2':1}

{ks[0]: reduce(int.__sub__, (d[k] for d, k in zip(ds, ks))) for ks in zip(*map(sorted, ds))}
```