# Как в matplotlib передвинуть оси координат в центр?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Есть график:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


X = np.linspace(-2,2,100)
Y = X**3

plt.plot(X, Y)
# псевод ось X
plt.plot([-2,2],[0,0], color='g')
# псевод ось Y
plt.plot([0,0], [-8,8], color='g')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зелеными линиями я показал куда хотел бы переместить оси координат, грубо говоря, как самым простым образом переместить оси с краев графика в центр ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plt.plot(X, Y)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[Пример получения осей для `subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.py):

```
# Two subplots, unpack the axes array immediately
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_title('Sharing Y axis')
ax2.scatter(x, y)

# Four axes, returned as a 2-d array
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2)
axarr[0, 0].plot(x, y)
axarr[0, 0].set_title('Axis [0,0]')
axarr[0, 1].scatter(x, y)
axarr[0, 1].set_title('Axis [0,1]')
axarr[1, 0].plot(x, y ** 2)
axarr[1, 0].set_title('Axis [1,0]')
axarr[1, 1].scatter(x, y ** 2)
axarr[1, 1].set_title('Axis [1,1]')
```

Comment: А как можно `ax = plt.gca()` на subplots разбить ?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.py - надо смотреть вариант с 2+ subplots...

Comment: Вылезла небольшая проблемка, там на старом месте осей сверху и с права две линии появилось, как их убрать ? вот у вас на графике они тоже есть

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч, они не появились, они остались...

Comment: Да, остались, их же убрать можно как нибудь ?

Comment: От души спасибо.